# how to support more than one datetime pattern

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

[image]

How to support more than one datetime pattern like `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-dd`?

Comment: your question is not understood.please explain what you really need

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Please do not post code as an image since it will make hard for others with your same problem to find your question.

Answer (score 0):

With `SimpleDateFormat`, you can set your own date patterns. For example, `dd/mm/yyyy`, `mm/dd/yyyy`, `yyyy-mm-dd`, and so on.

The following pattern letters are defined (all other characters from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are reserved):

```
Letter   Date or Time Component   Presentation       Examples
G        Era designator             Text                AD
y        Year                       Year                1996;    96
M        Month in year               Month               July; Jul; 07
w        Week in year               Number               27
W        Week in month               Number               2
D        Day in year               Number               189
d        Day in month               Number               10
F        Day of week in month       Number               2
E        Day in week               Text               Tuesday; Tue
a        Am/pm marker               Text               PM
H        Hour in day (0-23)       Number               0
k        Hour in day (1-24)       Number               24
K        Hour in am/pm (0-11)       Number               0
h        Hour in am/pm (1-12)       Number               12
m        Minute in hour           Number               30
s        Second in minute           Number               55
S        Millisecond                Number               978
z        Time zone                   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z        Time zone                  RFC 822 time zone   -0800

(from Java API doc)
```

[Source](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm)

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    try {
      Date date = format.parse("12/31/2006");
      System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // formatting
    System.out.println(format.format(new Date()));
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
Sun Dec 31 00:00:00 PST 2006
01/26/2007
```